# jQuery validate needs a different highlight methods for a certain input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to change the method of highlight slightly due to the required html of my form. So my form is validated with:

```
$('#training form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().addClass('error');
    },
    rules: {
        m38086fbrp__54 : 'required',
        m38086fbrp__55 : 'required',
        m38086fbrp__57 : 'required',
        m38086fbrp__58 : {
            email: true,
            required: true
        },
        m38086fbrp__56 : 'required',
        m38086fbrp__62 : 'required',
        m38086fbrp__67 : 'required',
        m38086fbrp__70 : 'required'
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass('error');
    }
});
```

I then need to have:

```
$('#training form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().parent().addClass('error');
    },
    rules: {
        'm38086fbrp__69[]' : 'required'
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass('error');
    }
});
```

As you can see it is just changing the highlight method slightly for a checkbox group.

Comment: Quote: _"As you can see it is just changing the highlight method slightly for a checkbox group."_ ~ No, we cannot "see" anything about a checkbox group.  Please post the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I need to change the method of highlight slightly due to the required html of my form."*

You would simply use a conditional inside the `highlight` callback function.

```
....
highlight: function(element) {
    if ( **some condition** ) {
        $(element).parent().parent().addClass('error');
    } else {
        $(element).parent().addClass('error');
    }
},
....
```

I cannot post a more detailed answer since you did not post any of the HTML markup, but you could try `$(element).is(':checkbox')`.